# Dimensions of confusion matrix after applying KMeans algorithm not as expected

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, confusion-matrix

I am developing a code in Python to apply KMeans clustering algorithm to a dataset. The number of clusters that I have initialized is 5. But after applying the algorithm and then predicting, I was curious to see the confusion matrix, to check how well the algorithm performed. My expectation was to get a 5 X 5 confusion matrix, instead I got a 10 X 10 matrix having the last 5 columns containing 0 values. Below is the code and confusion matrix. What am I doing wrong? How to get a 5X5 matrix, as per my number of clusters initialized?

```
`kmeans = KMeans(init = "random", n_clusters = 5, n_init = 5)
kmeans.fit(PCA_30)
predicted_labels = kmeans.predict(PCA_30
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(actual_labels, predicted_labels))`



[[  44  256 3519  280   33    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [   3    9    0   21 4651    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [ 123 2797   63  556  638    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [ 158  143   40 3570  440    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [3391  348    5    0  328    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [ 545  144   76 2036  994    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [  28 3538   76   80  415    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [3787   29   25    7  553    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [ 455  177   34 2283 1114    0    0    0    0    0]  
 [3602   80   38   95  373    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

Comment: How many actual labels do you have? 10?  This would only happen if the number of actual labels you had was 10, but the number of predicted labels is 5.  This is why the confusion matrix is 0 for the right side of the matrix because the actual labels 5 through 9 don't map to any labels in the k-means output.

Answer (score 0):

Confusion matrixes are for *classification*, not for clustering.

The clustering will predict 0 to 4. It won't correctly *predict* anything, because clustering is not predictive. The naming of the python methods is IMHO a bad idea. In fact, many clustering algorithms do not implement `predict` at all. KMeans is the rare exception because you can use a nearest-neighbor classifier on the centers to predict.

Usually confusion matrices are square, and the code you used probably enforces this - in classification, you want to see if a class is never predicted! And you probably have 10 classes here - mnist maybe?